# Case insensitive without importing modules. I need the original output and not the lower ones

Tags: function, loops, haskell, module, block

this is my code:

```
x = ["Hello","Nice","WELCOME"]
y = "HELLO"
app x y = filter (isInfixOf (map to Lower y)) (map (map toLower) x)
```

Output:
app x y -> ["hello"]

I need the original output ("HELLO") and not the lower one without importing modules.--

thank you

Answer (score 6):

You should only `map toLower` in the filter condition, not perform a mapping on the elements itself:

```
app :: [String] -> String -> [String]
app xs y = filter (isInfixOf (map toLower y) . map toLower) xs
```

Note that using `toLower x == toLower y` is however *not* a good way to do case insensitive matching: certain characters do not have an uppercase/lowercase variant, and the rules of matching two strings in a caseinsensitive manner are more complicated. Usually one uses [**`toCaseFold :: Text -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:toCaseFold) to normalize text to do case-*in*sensitive matching. For example:

```
ghci> map toLower "straße" == map toLower "strasse"
False
ghci> toCaseFold "straße" == toCaseFold "strasse"
True
```